# Why can't I get anything to stay inline on my nav bar after a form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am struggling with getting a navbar to contain:

1. My brand image
2. A long search bar and button to submit filling the entire navbar height
3. Enough room at the end of #2 for one more button of the same height

... all in one line, without collapsing.

However, for the life of me, I cannot get **anything to stay on the same line** as the nav bar after I place the search bar from #2. I have tried putting the search form in a column as in below, using `display: inline` in different places, `navbar-right`, etc.

Please let me know if this is an easy fix. I'd like to have some control over how long the search field is as well.

```css
#searchBar {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

#searchText {
  height: 62px;
}

#searchButton {
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: 0px;
  height: 63px;

}

#navigationBar {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -3px rgba(17, 17, 17, .16);
  height: 63px;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}

.logo-small {
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 19px;
  width: 49px;
}
```

```html
   <nav class="nav" id="navigationBar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/""><img src="mylogo.png" class="logo-small">BRAND IMAGE</a>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-10">
            <form>
                <div class="input-group" id="searchBar">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search here." onsubmit="search()">
                     <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button type="button" id="searchButton" onclick="this.blur();"><i class="flaticon-search"></i></button>
              </span>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    
           <!-- HERE is where I want to place another button to fill the remaining space in the nav bar -->
   </div
   
</nav>
```

Comment: (1) `<form>` is a block element so it will not line up beside other elements by default, so that's the element you need to position. (2) You can't just set one div to be a column - on its own it means nothing. You need to create a full grid structure, with rows containing columns. If you are trying to use Bootstrap, check their documentation on grids

Comment: @FluffyKitten Even when I create an out row, and then place the form as a `col-sm-10` and then another column as a `col-sm-2`, it appears on another line. How can I do this positioning you referenced?

Comment: As I said, you will need to refer to the documentation for whatever grid system you are trying to use. And also, you need to put the form etc *into* the columns, not the other way around.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've updated my question, but this has the exact same problem.

Comment: You are not using the grid system correctly - as I have said, *please read the documentation to learn how to use it properly*.

Answer (score -2):

I'm rewriting my original answer, because I made a couple of stupid assumptions, and didn't provide anything very helpful using the provided code.

As mentioned by others in previous comments, it might be most helpful to better understand grid layouts and how they work in a larger context.

Bootstrap has some great features specifically for grouping `form` elements and controls together, specifying how you'd like them to layout.

[Read more on that, here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/)

This snippet uses the grid system to divide the `nav` element into 12 columns, and uses the `col-[size]-[width]` classes to define how many "columns" each element  should occupy, and at which resolutions those rules should apply.

For example, you could use `col-lg-4` along with `col-xs-2` within the `class` attribute to tell that element to act differently at larger and smaller resolutions.

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal
>   to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller
>   devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element
>   will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large
>   devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

[The documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) specifies how these work together, and gives lots of examples with `@media` queries, so I'd recommend giving it a thorough read.

You may also want to look at using the `navbar` controls to better align form controls within the `nav` element itself.
[You can find some great examples of that, here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav).

Lastly, if you'd like to play with this example, [here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/Slothluvchunk/pen/prYeRQ?editors=1000).

Hope this answer helps you more than my last one did.

```css
#searchBar {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

#searchText {
  height: 62px;
}
#another_button {
  height: 62px;
}
.search_bar_button {
  height: 62px;
}

#searchBar input {
  width: 100%;
}

#searchButton {
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: 0px;
  height: 63px;
}

#navigationBar {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -3px rgba(17, 17, 17, .16);
  height: 63px;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.logo-small {
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 19px;
  width: 49px;
}

.another_button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="nav navbar navbar-default col-xs-12" id="navigationBar">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="mylogo.png" class="logo-small" />
      BRAND IMAGE
    </a>
  </div>
  <form class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group" id="searchBar">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="searchButton" class="btn search_bar_button" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search here." onsubmit="search()">
    </div>
  </form>                                                
  <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
    <span id="another_button" class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="another_button btn btn-secondary" type="button">Button 2</button>
    </span>
  </div>                                               
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't care about grid-based, but responsive is what I want. I just want everything to condense appropriately (without becoming collapsible ).

Comment: If responsive is the desired outcome, it would help the quality of answers to state that explicitly in the question.
You'll need to either implement @media queries to handle your specific `px` declarations, or use % based declarations instead.
You can also use a responsive framework and implement a grid12 layout (or similar) instead of the static `px` widths.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning - Just got back and am re-reading the initial source code and realized that I totally missed the boat on this one. Apologies for not noticing the bootstrap col classes and nav component in your initial example. I'm going to try to carve out some time to workup a better answer for you.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning - I updated my answer with a working example using Bootstrap 4's grid system. Hope that's helpful.